# How can I insert rows from an Oracle database into SQL Server table using bulkcopy C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, model-view-controller

I am developing an application to transfer about 1,000,000 rows from an Oracle database into a SQL Server table. And I hear bulk copy would be best.

Can someone please give me an example on how to do this? I am developing the application in C# ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was just *assuming* that you really mean **SQL Server** (the Microsoft database product) when you mention *SQL* (which is really only the *query  language* - not a database product)

Comment: Have you considered using Heterogeneous Services? It will allow you to create a DB link on the Oracle server which will connect to the SQL server, and transform the rows using a simple DML on either system.

Comment: Or SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) which is entirely designed for extracting data from a source (including Oracle), transforming/massaging it if necessary, then loading it to a target (including SQL Server in bulk load mode.) Someone proficient in SSIS could create a package to do this in ten minutes without writing a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The `BULK INSERT` statement is for importing data from an appropriately formatted file on disk. (the file format is a variant of CSV except without any ability to escape the row-terminator or field-terminator characters, which restricts its utility).

You would have to independently dump the Oracle data to a flat-file then import it using `BULK INSERT` however I don't feel this is the best way to accomplish your goal.

SQL Server supports the notion of "linked servers" which can be any ODBC-compliant data-source, including other database servers, provided they have an ODBC driver. Oracle, as it happens, does. All you have to do is add the Oracle server as a linked-server and then simply run this:

```
INSERT INTO sqlServerDatabaseTable ( Column1, Column2, etc... ) VALUES
SELECT
    Column1, Column2, etc...
FROM
    linkedServerName.databaseName.schemaName.tableName
```

And Bob's your uncle.